# How do I set hotkeys for my favorites?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, ps3

I can't seem to set my hotkeys on the PS3. I did it once on accident and can't seem to anymore.  I believe you're supposed to press left or right on the D-Pad to set it, but that isn't working for me.

I'm getting quite annoyed having to actually go into the favorites to switch from two swords to a bow.  Sometimes, when I switch back, I have to go into my inventory to manually equip the other sword as one is left unequipped.

How can I get my hotkeys working?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, open up your favorites and scroll to whatever you want to hotkey, then hold left or right on the D-pad until a 1 or 2 appears next to the item.  After exiting the favorites menu when you press left or right on the D-pad you should switch to whatever equipment you set with that direction.

I have also had issues with one sword being unequipped when using the favorites menu.  For me this usually happens when it is two of the same one-handed weapon so they show up as one entry in favorites.  The icon to show which hand it is in is fairly small and it is hard to  tell the difference between when it is L, when it is R, and when it is both.  Just tap R1 and L1 when your swords selected in the favorites menu until you can tell the difference easily.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I didn't know I had to hold it. I feel like a complete arse now. As for the swords, they are the same. Daedric Swords (Legendary). It's just annoying that it happens when I put a spell in my off-hand or something. Thanks, again.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get ride of that number set the hotkey to an item then drop it. It should work and remove which the number you set it on. Then pick it back up it you need it. It will completely remove it.

Comment: While this doesn't provide a direct answer to the question, it might help future users who want to unbind their hotkeys, therefore I'm not flagging this.