# Why do some favorites get a number put next to them?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, ps3

I noticed that rather randomly, my Unrelenting Force shout now has a 1. next to it in my favorites.  Later on, on a totally new character, a 2. popped up next to a different favorited item.

What causes this?  Is there any way to reverse it?  Is there any actual, intended use for these labels?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These are favorites you've bound to the left and right buttons on your joypad, allowing you to switch betweeen them by pressing the left or right button.

You can bind favorites to the left and right buttons by opening your favorites menu, and pressing the left or right button (left is 1, right is 2)

you can read more about it in [another question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/36903/how-do-i-set-hotkeys-for-my-favorites).

Comment: Thanks.  Is there a way to un-bind without binding to another?

Comment: @Iszi: On PC, you can remove hotkeys from favorites by un-favoriting and re-favoriting them.  That seems like it should also work on console.

Comment: @DaveSherohman Thanks.  I kind of figured that.  Haven't tried it yet though.  I just went ahead and assigned the hotkeys to things I might actually *use* - and, coincidentally, haven't used the hotkeys since.

Comment: hotkeys are genius if you play Khajiit, binding your nightvision to one of them is "crucial" (bind your normally used shout to the other).

Answer (score 0):

If you favorite a potion or a bow that you have multiple of, it should show the count to the right of the item name in the favorites menu too.